# Encryption at code vs Encryption at DB column

Tags: php, mysql, security, encryption, architecture

*Need to seek architectural advice  !*

Currently, have sensitive data at Database (say user's SSN) as plain text

It has to be encrypted.

**Approach 1: Encryption at Code**

- Some Crypto built in library can be used to encrypt (using key stored at vault)
- The EncryptedText can be stored to DB column
- For retrieval, SELECT upon this DB table from DAO, use Decrypt function at code, return Decrypted response

**Approach 2: Encrypt the DB's column**

- apply a trigger to column, which would encrypt INSERT data for that column
- For retrieval, database offers Decrypt methods which can be used at SELECT query at DAO layer

**Parameters to decide:**

1. Performance
2. Code quality (appears cleaner at Approach 2)
3. Encryption strength (would both approaches provide similar strength at encryption)

Currently, the application code is in **php Laravel** and DB is **MySQL**

Encryption algorithm planned to use: **AES 256 CBC**

Comment: One aspect you should consider is the key management, and how these options resolve it. Typically, some regulations require the app to rotate the key every 12 months. Can both those options handle the key rotation seamlessly? If you can't have down time, the live application should be able to handle two keys at the same time while the key is being rotated.

Comment: @TheImpaler Key rotation not required. We plan, even incase of a doubt about the secet key, we will re-Encrypt data with new key !

Comment: How vulnerable is the machine where the decryption key is held?  And many other places that need plugging.  You should really hire a security expert and not expect a complete answer from this "free" service.

Comment: @RickJames Key will stay at Hashicorp's in house hosted cloud server.

Comment: @RickJames I was more curious for which is a better approach ? encrypting at code.. or let DB take cae of enc-decyption. The DB's approach appears easier to plugin to existing system, as that will cause minimal code changes